# How can I make this GIMP/ImageMagick script?

Tags: python, imagemagick, gimp, script-fu

I'm using GIMP to do a simple but tedious operation for many images so I'd like to know how I can make a script that will do it for me, or find some simpler way of doing this.

I import an image file that has large dimensions but is mostly square, sometimes like 550x564, 580x596, etc., which may be jpg, bmp, or png, and I want to export a 192x192 PNG file, resized and cropped on both ends of the longer dimension, which is usually vertical but can be horizontal.

I perform the following steps for an image that is longer vertically than it is horizontally:

1. Image->Scale Image->Set **Width** to 192 (Locked, so Height will automatically be set to something like 196)
2. Click **Scale**
3. Image->Canvas Size->Set **Height** to 192
4. Click **Center**
5. Click **Resize**
6. File->Export As->same file name but extension changed to **.png**, and PNG image selected from the dropdown list (usually the original files are jpg, but sometimes they are png, so overwrite if necessary)
7. Click **Export** (Click Load Defaults)
8. Click **Export** again

How can I do this in script-fu or python for GIMP? Or in ImageMagick? Or is there a better way of making a macro for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understood you. Try this with **ImageMagick** to convert a single image:

```
convert input.jpg -gravity center -resize 192x192^ -extent 192x192 -set filename:base "%[basename]" "%[filename:base].png"
```

---

You could also potentially leverage the power of `mogrify` to do a whole directory full of images in one go, but be very careful, and try it out on a COPY of your files somewhere away from your main work. That will actually be easier, because you can let `mogrify` work out the filenames itself and you don't need a loop:

```
# Process all JPEGs in current directory
mogrify -format png -gravity center -resize 192x192^ -extent 192x192 *jpg
```

---

If you are on Windows, you may need to escape the caret (`^`), I don't use Windows, but I think you will either need to add an extra caret before it, or maybe enclose the whole `-resize` parameter in double quotes:

```
mogrify ... -resize "192x192^" ...
```

---

Note that if you are on **ImageMagick** v7+, `mogrify ...` becomes `magick mogrify ...`